# mouse in android application

Tags: android, cordova, touch

I want to have some object in my app that follows user touches and act like a mouse so user knows exactly where he touches on the screen.
I tried this code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
if (event.targetTouches.length == 1) {
    var obj = document.getElementById('mouse');
    var touch = event.targetTouches[0];
    obj.style.left = touch.pageX + 'px';
    obj.style.top = touch.pageY + 'px';
  }
}, false);
```

But the object only move to the touch position at the start and at the end of touch movments.
Then I figured out that in order to make the object to follow the touches of user I should call this function

```
event.preventDefault();
```

in my "touchmove" and "touchstart" events but when I call this function it seems that it disables all of my clickable component in the scene.
Is there any way that I can have both of these features?

Comment: I don't know anything about phonegap, but with android you often have to call invalidate() or postInvalidate() to update the canvas during an action like this.

Comment: It's not a canvas. when I add event.preventDefault() my buttons onclickes doesn't work.